# Use JQuery to get a specific TD in a series of Tables

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a mess of HTML TABLE tags and I am trying to use JQuery to drill down to a specific TD cell within all the generated TABLE's. The problem is I have JQuery getting the correct TD cell but its only getting the first cell in a series of TABLE's with the same structure.

Here is the JQuery that I am using that gets to the correct TD:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ($) {
        $(".dataContent div table tbody tr td").first().css("background", "yellow");
    });
</script>
```

Here is the HTML structure simplified:

```
<td class="dataContent">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <div>
        <table>...</table>
        <div>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#"><img /></a></td><!--this cell-->
                        <td><div>random cell</div></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!--Generated Tables with same structure as the TABLE above-->
            <table></table>
            <table></table>
            <table></table>
            <table></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

So I not only want to get the first cell in the first TABLE but also in all the generated TABLES below. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `td:first-child` instead of `.first()` to get all cells that are the first in their rows within every table:

```
$(".dataContent div table tbody tr td:first-child").css("background", "yellow");
```

Using the `:first` selector or the `.first()` method causes jQuery to return only the *very first* element out of all the elements that are matched, so it never looks beyond that one cell.

Comment: Arrr! I knew it was something easy but i feel stupid for missing this! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`$(".dataContent div table").eq(0).find('td').eq(0)` gives you the first TD in the first table.

`$(".dataContent div table").length` will give you the number of tables.

Make a loop. easy.

Comment: Thanks for posting, the other answer was an easier fix.